# How variable is declared inside if statement? js

Tags: javascript

How var a is declared? Is it global? What scope does it have?

```
if ((a = 10) > 0) {
...
}
```

Is it like this?

```
var a = 10;
if (a > 0) { ... }
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as if you did `a = 10` without the if statement.

Comment: Yes, its a global variable. You should use `use strict` to avoid such issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript variable scope in the IF statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964895/javascript-variable-scope-in-the-if-statement)

Comment: by the way, notice that (a = 10) will always be > 0.  The = will set a to 10, then return that 10 to the equation.