# jQuery javascript variable of the if-statement is not seen in else-Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement, scope

A small form should be used to make sure that selecting a specific element influences the selection of additional form fields.
To solve the problem I used the jQuery Change function.
With an If-Else Statement the desired results are delivered.
However, the change function does not return the desired result if the special variable 'shippingLocalPickup' is only declared within the IF statement.
([JS-FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ChristianKruse/nz2y72ae/))

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" id="checkboxNationalShippingService" name="checkboxNationalShippingService" value="yes" checked="checked" />
<select id="shippingServiceSel" name="shippingService">
  <option selected value='DE_Pickup'>Ware muss abgeholt werden</option>
  <option selected value='DHL_Paket'>Paket</option>
</select>
<div id="shippingLocalPickup" class="selElement" title="Diese Option sollte bei ja belassen werden">
  <p>Artikel kann abgeholt werden?
    <select name="shippingLocalPickup">
      <option selected value="DE_Pickup">ja</option>
      <option value="false">nein</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

the query script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shippingServiceSel")
      .change(function() {
        var shippingService = $("#shippingServiceSel").val();
        if (shippingService == "DE_Pickup") {
          var shippingLocalPickup = $("#shippingLocalPickup");
          shippingLocalPickup.empty().append('<p>Artikel kann abgeholt werden? <select name="shippingLocalPickup"><option value="false">nein</option><option value="true">ja</option></select></p>');
        } else {
          shippingLocalPickup.empty().append('<p>Artikel kann abgeholt werden? <select name="shippingLocalPickup"><option value="true">ja</option><option value="false">nein</option></select></p>');
        }
      })
  });
```

If it is declared at the beginning of the function, everything works fine.
([JS-FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ChristianKruse/hckpu28h/))

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shippingServiceSel")
      .change(function() {
        var shippingLocalPickup = $("#shippingLocalPickup");
        var shippingService = $("#shippingServiceSel").val();
        if (shippingService == "DE_Pickup") {

          shippingLocalPickup.empty().append('<p>Artikel kann abgeholt werden? <select name="shippingLocalPickup"><option value="false">nein</option><option value="true">ja</option></select></p>');

        } else {
          shippingLocalPickup.empty().append('<p>Artikel kann abgeholt werden? <select name="shippingLocalPickup"><option value="true">ja</option><option value="false">nein</option></select></p>');
        }
      })
  });
```

In my opinion, variables should be visible everywhere within a function. As described here:
([stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964895/javascript-variable-scope-in-the-if-statement/6964915#6964915))

Why is visibility still restricted in the if statement? Where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance...

---

Comment: `shippingLocalPickup` is "visible" but it is only initialized in the `if` branch, hence it is `undefined` in the `else` branch -> [MDN: `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of visibility of declaration.
It's a problem of *initialization*.

In this code:

> ```
> var shippingService = $("#shippingServiceSel").val();
> if (shippingService == "DE_Pickup") {
>   var shippingLocalPickup = $("#shippingLocalPickup");
>   shippingLocalPickup.empty().append('<p>Artikel kann abgeholt werden? <select name="shippingLocalPickup"><option value="false">nein</option><option value="true">ja</option></select></p>');
> } else {
>   shippingLocalPickup.empty().append('<p>Artikel kann abgeholt werden? <select name="shippingLocalPickup"><option value="true">ja</option><option value="false">nein</option></select></p>');
> }
> ```

When `shippingService` is *not* `"DE_Pickup"`,
then the `else` branch will be executed,
and at that point `shippingLocalPickup` is not yet initialized,
its value is `undefined`.
Since this variable is used by both branches of the `if` statement,
you must initialize it before the `if`.